# Comparing lists line by line

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have 2 lists with the same number of rows(120) but have different column sizes, 2 and 4. Here is an example:

```
list_1=[ 1    2          
         3    4
         5    6]

list_2=[ 1   2   3   4
         5   6   7   8
         4   3   2   1]
```

I want to compare both lists line by line and save the highest number. In other words, I want to compare line 1 from `list_1` and `list_2` and save the number with the highest value and do the same for the following lines.

Here is an example of the output desired:

```
list_3=[ 4      #result from list_2
         8      #result from list_2
         6]     #result from list_1
```

I have tried the `argmax`function, but when I use this  `argmax(list1, axis = 1)` it only return the indexes, not the actual value and if I use `argmax(array)` it returns the max value of the whole list.

I can look for the max value in each line using `for` and save it, but is there a specific function for this?

Comment: is your list a numpy array ? it is a multidimensional  list

Comment: oh yes, sorry. They are arrays with shape (120,2) and (120,4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the "lists" are indeed NumPy arrays, as suggested in the comments, you could use `np.max()` to first get the maximum for each line, separately for each list, and then get the maximum between the lists:

```py
import numpy as np

list_1 = np.array([[1, 2],
                   [3, 4],
                   [5, 6]])
list_2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [4, 3, 2, 1]])

line_max_1 = np.max(list_1, axis=1)
line_max_2 = np.max(list_2, axis=1)

np.max([line_max_1, line_max_2], axis=0)
```

```
array([4, 8, 6])
```